# python script returning list with double bracket

Tags: list

I have the following code in python 3. I'm trying to read a text file and output a list of numerical values. These values will then be used when searching through a number of pdf invoices.

Here is what I have for the text file portion:

```
txt_numbers = []

for file in os.listdir(my_path):
    if file[-3:] == "txt":
        with open(my_path + file, 'r') as txt_file:
            txt = txt_file.readlines()

            for line in txt:
                # get number between quotes
                num = re.findall(r'(?<=").*?(?=")', line)
                txt_numbers.append(num)

            for c, value in enumerate(txt_numbers, 1):
                print(c, value)
```

Here is what is the output:
[[], ['51,500.00'], ['6,000.00'], ['77,000.00'], ['37,000.00']]

Question: How do I remove the "[" from within the list. I would like to have just ['51,500.00', '6,000.00', etc...]

I tried doing new_text_numbers = (", ".join(txt_numbers)) and then print(new_text_numbers)

Answer (score 0):

Problem: I was appending a list with a list, which is allowed in python just not what I wanted.

Added lines:

```
new_num = (", ".join(num))
txt_numbers.append(new_num)
```

Solution:

```
txt_numbers = []

for file in os.listdir(my_path):
    if file[-3:] == "txt":
        with open(my_path + file, 'r') as txt_file:
            txt = txt_file.readlines()

            for line in txt:
                # get number between quotes
                num = re.findall(r'(?<=").*?(?=")', line)
                new_num = (", ".join(num))      
                txt_numbers.append(new_num)     

            for c, value in enumerate(txt_numbers, 1):
                print(c, value)
```